# Style background Color from a second click wont work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

my first click was fine it changed  the color background  but then when I added a second condition it wont work.

```js
var showBox = $('.show');

showBox.click(function(){
    if (parseInt($(this).attr('value')[0]) === 1 ){  
       $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
    }

   if (parseInt($(this).attr('value')[1]) === 2){  
       $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');   
    }else{
       alert('uh oh!')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main-cont" class="container">
  <div class="show" value=1>1</div>
  <div class="show" value=2>2</div>
  <div class="show" value=3>3</div>
  <div class="show" value=4>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `parseInt($(this).attr('value')[1]` should be `parseInt($(this).attr('value')[0]` maybe?

Comment: not sure you're trying to accomplish with `[0]` `[1]` array indexes. `attr` gives you a string, not an array.

Comment: Also, take a look at [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for testing things like this.

Comment: you should accept one of the answers if they were of any help to you!

Comment: what can i do to compliment them from giving correct ans.? i just got green checked the ans. that i am most comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM :**

The main problem comes from this expression `$(this).attr('value')[1]` when you're trying to access the second item of `.attr('value')` when it will return just one item.

The second one is using the `value` as direct attribute of `div` what makes your HTML invalid.

**SUGGESTED SOLUTION :**

You should use the **[`data-* attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-dataset)** since `value` isn't an attribute of `div` tag, so your HTML will looks like :

```
<div id="main-cont" class="container">
    <div class="show" data-value=1>1</div>
    <div class="show" data-value=2>2</div>
    <div class="show" data-value=3>3</div>
    <div class="show" data-value=4>4</div>
</div>
```

And you could get this value using the jQuery method **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)** :

```
$(this).data('value');
```

**NOTE :** NO needs for the parse `parseInt()` the JS will do that for you automatically.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
  var show_value = $(this).data('value');

  if ( show_value === 1 ){  
     $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
  }else if ( show_value === 2 ){
     $(this).css('backgroundColor','green');   
  }else{
      alert('uh oh!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main-cont" class="container">
  <div class="show" data-value=1>1</div>
  <div class="show" data-value=2>2</div>
  <div class="show" data-value=3>3</div>
  <div class="show" data-value=4>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation by adding the event Listener to the parent of all of those children element. Details are commented in the Snippet.

**BTW**, I changed the tags to form controls since they have the `value` attribute. AFAIK, `value` is exclusive to form element, `divs` should not have the `value` attribute.

**SNIPPET 1** (Vanilla JavaScript)

```js
// Reference the parent element
var main = document.getElementById('main-cont');

// Register the click event to the parent
main.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  /* If the node is the last in the capture
  || phase (i.e. target phase), then
  || that is event.target (node that's clicked)
  */
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    console.log('The value of clicked node is ' + target.value);
  }
}, false);

/* By taking advantage of the bubbling phase we can
|| determine the element that was clicked and act
|| accordingly. By calling our methods/functions
|| in the correct context of the clicked node
|| event.target
*/
```

```css
output {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="main-cont" class="container">
  <output class="show" value=1> 1
  </output>
  <output class="show" value=2> 2
  </output>
  <output class="show" value=3> 3
  </output>
  <output class="show" value=4> 4
  </output>
</fieldset>
```

**SNIPPET 2** (jQuery)

```js
/* Delegate the click event by using the.on()
|| method. All nodes with the class of .show
|| is assigned as the context (which will
|| make `this` referenced to the node clicked
*/
$(document).on('click', '.show', function(event) {

  // Store the value of `this` in a var
  var value = $(this).val();

  // Use the css() method to change `this` style
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

  console.log('The value of the clicked node is ' + value);
});
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset id="main-cont" class="container">
  <output class="show" value=1> 1
  </output>
  <output class="show" value=2> 2
  </output>
  <output class="show" value=3> 3
  </output>
  <output class="show" value=4> 4
  </output>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @crisamdegracia great, although you have already accepted an appropriate answer, you can still upvote my answer by clicking the up arrow.